# Issue with `cases` of `amsmath`

Tags: amsmath, cases, braces

**Problem description**:

using the following latex code:

```
\[   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & x\leq a \\
\frac{x-a}{b-a} & a\leq x\leq b \\
\frac{c-x}{c-b} & b\leq x\leq c \\
1 & c\leq x \\
\end{array} 
\right. \]
```

I obtain this:
[image]

While the expected result was:

[image]

I have the same issue using `cases` of `amsmath`. For example:

```
\begin{equation}
    X=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if}\ a=1 \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
```

The result is:

[image]

**Question**: I do not even know what to look for. The file `style.txt` is a huge file with hundreds of lines. Any suggestions about the possible causes of this problem? A cannot even create a minimal example.

**Update**:

The line \usepackage{breqn} cause that problem. If I delete (or comment is), this issue disappears. However, other parts of the `.tex` contain this code that I need to delete and re-write in some other way:

```
\begin{dmath}
\begin{split}
    \label{eq:something}
    x_e = x_0 + \gamma (x_r - x_{0})
    = x_0 + \gamma(\cancel{x_0} + \alpha (x_0 - x_{n+1}) - \cancel{x_0})
    = x_0 + \gamma \alpha (x_0 - x_{n+1})
    \end{split}
\end{dmath}
```

Is possible that some package create conflicts between them?

Comment: you appear to have redefined `\{` not to be a stretchy character but just to have a fixed size, but without showing your code it's hard to guess how you have done that. Start with a copy of your document with just the first expression and then delete every package and definition that you can delete while still showing the problem, and post the resulting test document.

Comment: Maybe you don't need all those hundreds of lines? Start with an empty document using your documentclass. Add _only_ `\usepackage{amsmath}` and your two examples. Verify that it works correctly (I just did, it works with `\documentclass{article}`). Then start adding the content from your original document, small pieces at a time, and recompile every time you add a small piece. Whenever you get an error because you use some command from a package, add that package. Continue until either you have added your full document without problems, or until you encounter the issue,

Comment: then you have your MWE and you can ask about it here. In any case the end result will be a document that is most likely much cleaner than you have now, and that also probably compiles faster.

Comment: doing just like that! I will post the solution as soon as I find it, thank you guys

Comment: problem found but not the solution: the line `\usepackage{breqn}` cause that problem. If I delete (or comment is), this issue desappears. However, other part of the book are not compiled in this case. Any idea? ..updating the question with this information

Comment: Good that you found the issue. It would be helpful if you add a full minimal compilable example to your questions, such that this example can be copied, compiled without any changes, and then shows the problem that you describe (so with the documentclass, the usepackage statements, begin and end document included).

Comment: ...preparing a minimal working example

Comment: problem solved and question updated. The package is deleted. This, unfortunately, causes us to change some parts of the texts somewhere else (impossible to use `\begin{dmath}`). Is it possible that some packages are in conflict between themself?

Comment: @Leos313 you still haven't posted an example that people can run to see the issue. But to your "is it possible" question, then `breqn` is _by design_ incompatible with almost any other latex math package, it redefines _everything_ related to math and is highly experimental (and its original author died many years ago). So yes it is not only possible but highly likely that it clashes with other packages.

Answer (score 1):

To big for comment:

Your code fragment works as expected. Also works fine `cases` (from `amsmath`} as well `dcases` (from `mathtools`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & x\leq a \\
\dfrac{x-a}{b-a} & a\leq x\leq b \\
\dfrac{c-x}{c-b} & b\leq x\leq c \\
1 & c\leq x \\
        \end{array}
\right.
\]

\[ 
\begin{cases}
0 & x\leq a \\
\dfrac{x-a}{b-a} & a\leq x\leq b \\
\dfrac{c-x}{c-b} & b\leq x\leq c \\
1 & c\leq x \\
\end{cases}
\]


\[
\begin{dcases}
0 & x\leq a \\
\frac{x-a}{b-a} & a\leq x\leq b \\
\frac{c-x}{c-b} & b\leq x\leq c \\
1 & c\leq x \\
\end{dcases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know, I have updated the question with more info

Comment: the line \usepackage{breqn} cause that problem. If I delete (or comment is), this issue disappears. However, other parts of the book are not compiled in this case. Any idea?

Comment: @Leos313, new information s are not sufficient. you need to provide MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: ok! preparing it

Comment: @Leos313, where is this line in your code fragment? Simply, don't use this package. Better result you will achieve with manually breaking your long equations into more lines. Or if you persist to use this package, load it before `mathtools`.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the use of that package. But the book is a big book :) it is not that simple. However, I am trying to find a solution. I will update the question asap

Comment: @Leos313, no one claims that typesetting of book is "by-the-way" task :-(

Comment: problem solved and question updated. The package is deleted. This, unfortunately, causes to change some parts of the texts somewhere else (impossible to use `\begin{dmath}`). Is it possible that some packages are in conflict between themself?

Comment: @Leos313 -- Nothing here identifies almost any packages except `breqn`, or the document class.  Without more information, all attempts here to help are only guesses.